# How many unitTime(10 mins, half hour) there are between 2 localTime? Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, time, java-8

I want to define a unit Time for example, 12 minutes or 25 minutes, for know how many unit Times there are between 2 LocalTime in Java.

For Example, if I defined 15 minutes like unit time, between 8:00 and 10:00, I should get 8 times.

Comment: `LocalDate` only stores dates, not times, so there is no "between 8:00 and 10:00" when using `LocalDate`

Comment: SOrry is localTime

Comment: Did you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), to see if there is any methods that can help with that? What did you try? --- *Hint: see `until`*

Comment: I try this: ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(start, end) but the problem is that ChronoUnito only have unitTime already defined, but I need specify my own unit time.

Comment: "ChronoUnito only have unitTime already defined" then use multiplication and division. If you have X minutes between 2 dates, then you have X/20 "20 minute" intervals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class to get the duration between two LocalTime values. Then you can calculate the custom time units yourself:

```
int minutesUnit = 15;
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.of(8, 0);
LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.of(10, 0);
Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, endTime);
long unitsCount = duration.toMinutes() / minutesUnit;
System.out.println(unitsCount);
```

This prints `8`.

If you have different time units you could break the duration down to millis and calculate the result:

```
long millisUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15);
// ...
long unitsCount = duration.toMillis() / millisUnit;
```

Comment: this can also be achieved with `ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between` that OP already used

Answer (score 4):

```
    Duration unit = Duration.ofMinutes(15);

    LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(8, 0);
    LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(10, 0);

    long howMany = Duration.between(start, end).dividedBy(unit);

    System.out.println("" + howMany + " units");
```

Output:

> 8 units

Since Java 9 `Duration` has had a `dividedBy(Duration)` method, just what you need here.

The limitation is it gives you only whole units. Had the unit been 25 minutes, the result would be 4 (not 4.8) units.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a custom [`TemporalUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html) that is based on an arbitrary (positive) [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). You can then use it like you use any built-in [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html), e.g.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("08:00");
LocalTime end   = LocalTime.parse("10:00");

DurationUnit min15 = DurationUnit.ofMinutes(15);
System.out.println(min15.between(start, end)); // prints: 8
System.out.println(start.until(end, min15));   // prints: 8
System.out.println(start.plus(3, min15));      // prints: 08:45
```

```
DurationUnit min7 = DurationUnit.ofMinutes(7);
System.out.println(min7.between(start, end)); // prints: 17
System.out.println(start.until(end, min7));   // prints: 17
System.out.println(start.plus(3, min7));      // prints: 08:21
```

Custom `TemporalUnit`:

```
public final class DurationUnit implements TemporalUnit {

    private static final int SECONDS_PER_DAY = 86400;
    private static final long NANOS_PER_SECOND =  1000_000_000L;
    private static final long NANOS_PER_DAY = NANOS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_PER_DAY;

    private final Duration duration;

    public static DurationUnit of(Duration duration)   { return new DurationUnit(duration); }
    public static DurationUnit ofDays(long days)       { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofDays(days)); }
    public static DurationUnit ofHours(long hours)     { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofHours(hours)); }
    public static DurationUnit ofMinutes(long minutes) { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofMinutes(minutes)); }
    public static DurationUnit ofSeconds(long seconds) { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofSeconds(seconds)); }
    public static DurationUnit ofMillis(long millis)   { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofMillis(millis)); }
    public static DurationUnit ofNanos(long nanos)     { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofNanos(nanos)); }

    private DurationUnit(Duration duration) {
        if (duration.isZero() || duration.isNegative())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duration may not be zero or negative");
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return this.duration;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDurationEstimated() {
        return (this.duration.getSeconds() >= SECONDS_PER_DAY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDateBased() {
        return (this.duration.getNano() == 0 && this.duration.getSeconds() % SECONDS_PER_DAY == 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTimeBased() {
        return (this.duration.getSeconds() < SECONDS_PER_DAY && NANOS_PER_DAY % this.duration.toNanos() == 0);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <R extends Temporal> R addTo(R temporal, long amount) {
        return (R) this.duration.multipliedBy(amount).addTo(temporal);
    }

    @Override
    public long between(Temporal temporal1Inclusive, Temporal temporal2Exclusive) {
        return Duration.between(temporal1Inclusive, temporal2Exclusive).dividedBy(this.duration);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.duration.toString();
    }

}
```