# How to round it down to the closest 5 minute interval if it is 1,2,3,4 minutes ahead?

Tags: java, java-8, instant, localdatetime

I want to round down an Instant / LocalDateTime to its closest 5 minutes interval in Java.

Examples: Suppose the time is:

```
2021-02-08T19:01:49.594
```

or

```
2021-02-08T19:02:49.594
```

or

```
2021-02-08T19:03:49.594
```

or

```
2021-02-08T19:04:49.594
```

Expected result:

```
2021-02-08T19:00:00.000
```

Comment: You could convert to seconds, subtract that value modulo 5, and convert back to a date.

Comment: Souma - I think you jave already got this answer from https://stackoverflow.com/q/66149567/10819573 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66169944/10819573. It will be helpful if you can describe any further doubt you may have.

Comment: that was a bit of different requirement.

Comment: We were rounding off 19:01 and 19:02 to 19:00 and 19:03 and 19:04 to 19:05, here what I want is to round down to 19:00 for all 4 of the above times.

Comment: `d = d.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES).minusMinutes(d.getMinute()%5);` and in case you coming back with another “bit of different requirement” soon, rounding up is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37613071/2711488).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can truncate it to [`ChronoUnit.MINUTES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#MINUTES) and then check the minute-of-hour as per the requirement i.e. if it is not a multiple of `5` subtract the remainder when divided by `5`. Use [`LocalDate#withMinute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#withMinute-int-) to return a copy of this `LocalDateTime` with the minute-of-hour altered.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String[] arr = { "2021-02-08T19:02:49.594", "2021-02-08T19:56:49.594", "2021-02-08T19:54:49.594",
                "2021-02-08T19:06:49.594" };

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(roundToNearestHour(s).format(dtf));
        }
    }

    static LocalDateTime roundToNearestHour(String str) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(str).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        int minute = ldt.getMinute();
        int remainder = minute % 5;
        if (remainder != 0) {
            ldt = ldt.withMinute(minute - remainder);
        }
        return ldt;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-02-08T19:00:00.000
2021-02-08T19:55:00.000
2021-02-08T19:50:00.000
2021-02-08T19:05:00.000
```

Answer (score 14):

For a more general purpose, reusable solution, implement a custom [`TemporalUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html) to be used with the [`truncatedTo​(TemporalUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) method. Below is an implementation copied from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55190881/5221149).

You then simply use it to call `truncatedTo()` with a 5 minute "unit". It works with both `LocalDateTime` and `Instant`.

```java
String[] inputs = { "2021-02-08T19:01:49.594", "2021-02-08T19:02:49.594",
                    "2021-02-08T19:03:49.594", "2021-02-08T19:04:49.594",
                    "2021-02-08T19:26:49.594", "2021-02-08T19:27:49.594",
                    "2021-02-08T19:28:49.594", "2021-02-08T19:29:49.594" };
for (String input : inputs) {
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input);
    Instant instant = Instant.parse(input + "Z");
    System.out.printf("%s -> %s   %s -> %s%n",
                      dateTime, dateTime.truncatedTo(DurationUnit.ofMinutes(5)),
                      instant, instant.truncatedTo(DurationUnit.ofMinutes(5)));
}
```

*Output*

```
2021-02-08T19:01:49.594 -> 2021-02-08T19:00   2021-02-08T19:01:49.594Z -> 2021-02-08T19:00:00Z
2021-02-08T19:02:49.594 -> 2021-02-08T19:00   2021-02-08T19:02:49.594Z -> 2021-02-08T19:00:00Z
2021-02-08T19:03:49.594 -> 2021-02-08T19:00   2021-02-08T19:03:49.594Z -> 2021-02-08T19:00:00Z
2021-02-08T19:04:49.594 -> 2021-02-08T19:00   2021-02-08T19:04:49.594Z -> 2021-02-08T19:00:00Z
2021-02-08T19:26:49.594 -> 2021-02-08T19:25   2021-02-08T19:26:49.594Z -> 2021-02-08T19:25:00Z
2021-02-08T19:27:49.594 -> 2021-02-08T19:25   2021-02-08T19:27:49.594Z -> 2021-02-08T19:25:00Z
2021-02-08T19:28:49.594 -> 2021-02-08T19:25   2021-02-08T19:28:49.594Z -> 2021-02-08T19:25:00Z
2021-02-08T19:29:49.594 -> 2021-02-08T19:25   2021-02-08T19:29:49.594Z -> 2021-02-08T19:25:00Z
```

Being general purpose, it can actually be used with `Instant`, `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, `LocalTime`, and `OffsetTime`, and it can be used with any time period that divides into a full day (e.g. 180 seconds, or 5 minutes, or 2 hours, but not 7 minutes).

```java
System.out.println(Instant.now().truncatedTo(DurationUnit.ofHours(2)));
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(DurationUnit.ofHours(2)));
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now().truncatedTo(DurationUnit.ofHours(2)));
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now().truncatedTo(DurationUnit.ofHours(2)));
System.out.println(LocalTime.now().truncatedTo(DurationUnit.ofHours(2)));
System.out.println(OffsetTime.now().truncatedTo(DurationUnit.ofHours(2)));
```

*Output*

```
2021-02-15T06:00:00Z
2021-02-15T02:00
2021-02-15T02:00-05:00
2021-02-15T02:00-05:00[America/New_York]
02:00
02:00-05:00
```

*Custom TemporalUnit*

```java
public final class DurationUnit implements TemporalUnit {

    private static final int SECONDS_PER_DAY = 86400;
    private static final long NANOS_PER_SECOND =  1000_000_000L;
    private static final long NANOS_PER_DAY = NANOS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_PER_DAY;

    private final Duration duration;

    public static DurationUnit of(Duration duration)   { return new DurationUnit(duration); }
    public static DurationUnit ofDays(long days)       { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofDays(days)); }
    public static DurationUnit ofHours(long hours)     { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofHours(hours)); }
    public static DurationUnit ofMinutes(long minutes) { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofMinutes(minutes)); }
    public static DurationUnit ofSeconds(long seconds) { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofSeconds(seconds)); }
    public static DurationUnit ofMillis(long millis)   { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofMillis(millis)); }
    public static DurationUnit ofNanos(long nanos)     { return new DurationUnit(Duration.ofNanos(nanos)); }

    private DurationUnit(Duration duration) {
        if (duration.isZero() || duration.isNegative())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duration may not be zero or negative");
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return this.duration;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDurationEstimated() {
        return (this.duration.getSeconds() >= SECONDS_PER_DAY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDateBased() {
        return (this.duration.getNano() == 0 && this.duration.getSeconds() % SECONDS_PER_DAY == 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTimeBased() {
        return (this.duration.getSeconds() < SECONDS_PER_DAY && NANOS_PER_DAY % this.duration.toNanos() == 0);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <R extends Temporal> R addTo(R temporal, long amount) {
        return (R) this.duration.multipliedBy(amount).addTo(temporal);
    }

    @Override
    public long between(Temporal temporal1Inclusive, Temporal temporal2Exclusive) {
        return Duration.between(temporal1Inclusive, temporal2Exclusive).dividedBy(this.duration);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.duration.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @andreas. I found a bug that causes compile error and wanted to edit the answer, but the "Suggested edit queue is full". I fixed the compile error in the `DurationUnit#between(Temporal, Temporal)` method by replacing the method contents with: `return Duration.between(temporal1Inclusive, temporal2Exclusive).dividedBy(this.duration.toMillis()).toMillis();` I've tested it and it's working as expected.

Comment: This is a great solution and something that should be provided by the core Java runtime, not something we need to roll ourselves :(